# Changing the origin of an image lay over the polar plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, annotations

I am adding a small logo in a polar plot.

I am using python to do that.

I use the following code to do this.

```
Logo = mpimg.imread(figpath+figname)
imagebox = OffsetImage(Logo, zoom=0.12)
ab = AnnotationBbox(imagebox, (4.7, 8))
ax1.add_artist(ab)
ax1.set_ylim(0,8)
```

The output is as follow:

[image]

The coordinate `(theta,r)` in `AnnotationBbox` starts at the center of the logo.

I want to move the logo to the location as shown in the red box below:

[image]

Can anyone advise me how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `box_alignment=` to `AnnotationBbox` to change the reference point for the box. For instance passing `box_alignment=(1,1)` makes the top right corner the reference `xy` coordinates.

```
from matplotlib.offsetbox import OffsetImage, AnnotationBbox

r = np.arange(0, 2, 0.01)
theta = 2 * np.pi * r

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='polar')
ax.plot(theta, r)
ax.set_rmax(2)
ax.set_rticks([0.5, 1, 1.5, 2])  # Less radial ticks
ax.set_rlabel_position(-22.5)  # Move radial labels away from plotted line
ax.grid(True)

img = matplotlib.image.imread("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/7/7d/Lenna_%28test_image%29.png")
imagebox = OffsetImage(img, zoom=0.12)
ab = AnnotationBbox(imagebox, xy=(np.pi*225/180, 2), box_alignment=(1,1))
ax.add_artist(ab)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Note that you can also change the coordinate system used to place the box. For instance if you want to put your logo in the top left corner of your figure, you could do:

```
ab = AnnotationBbox(imagebox, xy=(0,1), xycoords='figure fraction', box_alignment=(0,1))
```